# What is the use case of md-no-select-click in angularJs material tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

As it stated in [AngularJs Material 1.x official docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs) md-no-select-click

> When enabled, click events will not be fired when selecting tabs

What is the real use case of this feature?

Comment: I've checked the source code and found only one usage of this attribute in [this](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/tabs/js/tabsController.js#L340) function. I've checked this `select` function and it seems like the condition `if (canSkipClick && ctrl.noSelectClick) return;` will never be executed because `canSkipClick` is always undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Angular Lead Maintainer here https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10947#issuecomment-390435270

> When true, click events will not be fired when the value of `md-active` on an `md-tab` changes. This is useful when using tabs with UI-Router's child states, as triggering a click event in that case can cause an extra tab change to occur.

And more explanation here https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10947#issuecomment-390433726

> The original idea was that ui-router's directive listened for a click event and this would prevent the initial selection from passing a click event. So if you had a set of tabs which were used for navigation and each tab tied to a route, you could add this attribute to fix loading a route besides the first tab sending you back to the first tab because of the initial selection firing the click event and triggering a navigation.